# HTTP response to POST and GET

Tags: html, http, post, get

Assuming we're talking about the same content being returned, are HTTP responses to POST and GET identical? With GET, all I have to do to access something like an image is point my browser to the URL. With POST however, I can't seem to figure out any way of doing the same. How would I do a POST and display the image in the response using nothing more than simple HTML, and without the need for client-side scripting to handle the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a form pointing to the image's URL and submit it.

```
<form action="image.png" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Whether that's supported by the server in question is a question only you can answer.

Such a construct at least doesn't make sense. GET is intented for idempotent requests and POST for non-idempotent requests.

Comment: I agree, but the reason I'm using POST in this case is because there are too many parameters that need to be passed.

Comment: Just make them shorter and/or serialize them and/or use the path info. If you stucks, ask a new question. This is offtopic from your initial question.

Comment: No, there isn't. The `<img src>` fires implicitly a GET request.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment without realizing you had already replied. I did a quick search and found the same thing. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 0):

You might like the POST-REDIRECTT-GET pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get. Each browser will handle that correctly without client-side scripting, and it does not break the GET/POST semantics.